# random matching pairs without test repitition

Tags: python, random, matching

I have a treatment and control lists, with 10% of the users in control and rest 90% in tests.

```
control=range(1,11)#create sample control ids
test=range(11,101)#create sample test ids
```

Now I want to randomly generate pairs of control and test with following rules:

1. Each control can be mapped to only 2 treatments without repetition. It means our output should look like:

   (1,31), (1,39), (2,26), (2,81).....

So once test 31 is matched to control 1, it cannot be matched to any other control.

2. Secondly in the above case I have taken only two treatments. But I want it to be passed as a parameter, so that any number of treatments can be matched.

Comment: Is there a limit on the number of treatments to be matched? I mean, if 50 treatments are matched per control, then after two controls, the treatment ids will be depleted for example. How do you handle that case?

Comment: Yes in actual it is 9 treatments per control...also this is just an example...In actual we have 400K+ users...so in control we 4k users...so the match occurs entirely...above situation do not arises.....

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this, and to choose we need more information. Could the number of treatments per control vary or will it always be the same? Do you want to minimize the memory used, the time needed to generate each pair, or something else? Do the treatments need to be truly as random as possible or can they just have a non-obvious order?

Comment: @RoryDaulton: Good follow-up questions. So the number of treatments would be same for one single run. Once a parameter has been assigned a value, then every control should be assigned to that many treatments. Memory is not a constraint, but as mentioned we have a huge base of 400k+ users. But as of now I am concerned of a workable solution. Any non-obvious order is fine. See why I want to do randomly is that these users have absolute zero response. So any matching algorithm would not work. Hence just for sake of creating pairs I need some assignment. It can be random or non obvious order.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

control = np.array(range(1, 11))  # create sample control ids
test = np.array(range(11, 101))  # create sample test ids


def assign_treatments(treatment_per_control , control_ids, test_ids):
    control_treatment_pairs = []
    for control_id in control_ids:
        random_indices = np.random.choice(len(test_ids), treatment_per_control, replace=False)
        treatment_ids = test_ids[random_indices]
        test_ids = np.delete(test_ids, random_indices)
        for treatment_id in treatment_ids:
             control_treatment_pairs.append((control_id, treatment_id))
    return control_treatment_pairs

control_treatment_pairs = assign_treatments(treatment_per_control=2, control_ids=control, test_ids=test)
for pair in control_treatment_pairs:
    print(pair)
```

Which outputs in a sample run:

```
(1, 73)
(1, 44)
(2, 50)
(2, 77)
(3, 51)
(3, 17)
(4, 93)
(4, 42)
(5, 45)
(5, 82)
(6, 55)
(6, 81)
(7, 91)
(7, 76)
(8, 71)
(8, 70)
(9, 84)
(9, 11)
(10, 43)
(10, 23)
```

If you have any experience with numpy, you can try the above solution. It basically samples from the test array without replacement, so it is guaranteed that each control id gets unique test ids. The selected test ids are removed from the test array in each iteration. But in any case, you should be careful to handle the case when `control_id_count*treatment_per_control` exceeds `test_id_count`. This solution assumes that `treatment_per_control` remains the same for each control id.

Comment: When I execute the above code, it gives me 2 pairs for only first control. Rest of the control pairs are missing.

Comment: There is an extra indent in the last return statement...I have edited it.

Comment: I added a for loop to print the pairs. Can you check its output?

Comment: As explained..there is an extra indent in last return statement...please edit the answer...rest is fine..